# How to open only the directories ending with string?

Tags: python, pandas, directory

I have a directory `Data` and inside of it, I have lots of other directories whose pattern is 'customer_id2344`, in which case the number changes from directory to directory. Inside these directories are other directories and inside these directories files.

Data/customer_id'somenumber'/prices/file

I have a list of the number the customers that are important, defined as a variable, called it `points`.

```
points = [17835 34049 34050 34051 34052 34053 34054 34055 34056 34057 4058 34059  34060 17872 17873 17874 17875 17876 17877 17878 17879 17880 17882 17883  17884 17885 17886 17887 17888 17889 17890 17891 17892 19530 19531 21366]
```

And I want to get the data only from the customers that are important. I tried something like this:

```
path = "/home/marlon/.../"

df = pd.DataFrame()

for dirpath, subfld, files in os.walk(path):
    for i in pontos:
        if dirpath.endswith(str(i)):
            subfld = path + dirpath
            if os.path.isdir(subfld):
                aux = pd.DataFrame()
                sn = subfld.split('_id')[1]
                for arch in os.listdir(subfld):
                        subsubfld = subfld + "/" + arch 
                        for file in os.listdir(subsubfld):
                            filepath = os.path.join(subsubfld, file)
                            if os.path.isfile(filepath):
                                new_col = pd.read_parquet(filepath)
                                aux = pd.concat([aux, new_col])
                aux['id_cliente'] = sn
                df = df.append(aux)
     print(df)
```

However, `endswith()` method doesn't get only the folders ending with the numbers in the variable `points`, but gives me a boolean value. 
Instead of getting the data, I get an empty DataFrame:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

What method can I use?

Thanks

Comment: Use `endswith` as a test, if `True` add that file to a list and you  will have a list of all files you want

Comment: Did you check glob.glob?  Here is a link to the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.htm

Comment: @d_kennetz I did now what you've told me and it didn't work. Because I have three folders and then the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be helpful.

```py
for fld, i in zip(os.listdir(path), pontos):
    if(fld.endswith(i))
        subfld = path + fld
        if os.path.isdir(subfld):
            aux = pd.DataFrame()
                ...
```

Comment: The way @MarlonTeixeira have created dataframe it will be always empty. `pd.DataFrame()` will create an empty dataframe perhaps you might want to pass in some file object ?

Answer (score 0):

`endswith` will just check for a string ending with certain characters. But, if you need to list only the directories ending with integers you can use `glob`

```
import glob
import os
for value in glob.glob('dir/*[0-9]'):
    if os.path.isdir(value):
        #do something with the directory
```

Comment: The problem here is that I don't want the customers whose number ends with "0-9". I have a variable  called `points` whose values are something like `2344, 9486, 7938, 4935...`

Comment: then replace [0-9] with the points. It is string manipulation.